# phonegap code to make a call from voice input

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I want to develop an application for making a call from a voice input.The functionality should be that call must be forwarded when user speaks the name of the contact that exists in the device.I have got the plugins for the speech recognizer from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SpeechRecognizer.But I am not getting how to do the above functionality using it?
Can anyone help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well once you get the result in the success callback of window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize you would use that as the the filter parameter for the contacts.find method:

```
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter=speechResult; 
    options.multiple
    var fields = ["displayName", "name", "phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Then in the onSuccess you need to get the phone number, you'll have to decide which of the multiple phone numbers the contact may have in order to use it. I'm just going to assume the first for this answer. Then you set document.location to a "tel:" url to make the call.

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    if (contacts.length == 1) {
        if (contacts[0].phoneNumbers != null) {
            document.location = "tel:" + contacts[0].phoneNumbers[0];
        }
    }
}
```

That should about do it.

Comment: Thats fine.But I want the exact code for the speech recognition and matching it with the contacts in the device with its explanation.